# Advance filter for 9999 data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

There is limitation for range in advance filter data?
I had around 9999 data and try to create filter in user form, but when i try it error 1004 occur in line "Set tblRange = WSC.Range("A5:L9999" & irow)". but when i tried to delete the data in sheet to 999 its working. there is any limitatin on advance filter? thank you

```
Private Sub txtsearchfor_Change()
Dim irow As Long
Dim tblRange As Range, tblCriteria As Range
Dim WSC As Object

Set WSC = Worksheets("Catalog")
WSC.Activate
irow = WSC.Cells(WSC.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set tblRange = WSC.Range("A5:L9999" & irow)
Set tblCriteria = WSC.Range("X1:X2")
WSC.Range("X1") = cbsearchby
WSC.Range("X2") = "*" & txtsearchfor & "*"
'tblRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, tblCriteria
tblRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, tblCriteria, WSC.Range("AA5:AL9999"), False

Call GetCatalogSearchData
End Sub
```

Im trying to able to filter the data.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: MS Excel 2019 64bit

Comment: I guess you have the range definition wrong: if `irow` = 100, the term `WSC.Range("A5:L9999" & irow)`  would result in `WSC.Range("A5:L9999100")`. Do you want to have the end row hardcoded 9999 or is the last row `irow`? In that case use WSC.Range("A5:L" & irow)`

Comment: @FunThomas its working nowww... thank you so mucchhh... my baddd... thank you...